# Сохранение структуры текста, при копировании, в виде колонки

Tags: html, css

На страницах сайта есть колонка текста прописанная в виде

```
`<p>
..... <bp>
...... <bp>
... ..... <bp>
</p>
```

Но при копировании текста с сайта, сбивает структуру и текст копируется подряд

```
..... ...... ...... ... .....
```

Пример с со страницы :

```
Мечтать видеть тебя вновь,<br>
Листать книги своих снов<br>
Пора перестать давно<br>
Это странно, бесцельно, <br>
Ненужно, неправильно.<br>
<br>
Бледнеть и направленье менять,<br>
Вертеть память свою вспять,<br>
Лететь, в самую пропасть стремясь,<br>
Я уже не умею, не смею,<br>Не стану я.<br>
<br>
```

Как это исправить по минимуму изменив текст?

Сам [сайт сборник творчества певицы](https://alisa-music.ru/music/sad_about_me) Я разработчик сайта и обнаружил "косяк", мне нужно чтобы когда посетители копировали текст у него сохранялась структура колонки

> **Проблемам была в доп скипте

```
<script>
document.oncopy = function () {
var bodyElement = document.body; 
var selection = getSelection(); 
var href = document.location.href;
href=href.replace('/music','')
var copyright = ' alisa-music.ru'; 
<!-- var copyright = '<a href="'+ href +'">' + " alisa-music.ru " + '</a>'; ->
var text = selection + copyright;
var divElement = document.createElement('div'); 
divElement.style.position = 'absolute'; 
divElement.style.left = '-99999px'; 
text1 = document.createTextNode(text); //создал текстовый узел
divElement.appendChild(text1); //и добавил его
bodyElement.appendChild(divElement); 
selection.selectAllChildren(divElement); 
setTimeout(function(){
bodyElement.removeChild(divElement); 
}, 0);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<p itemprop="text">
  Мечтать видеть тебя вновь,<br>
  Листать книги своих снов<br>
  Пора перестать давно<br>
  Это странно, бесцельно, <br>
  Ненужно, неправильно.<br>
  <br>
  Бледнеть и направленье менять,<br>
  Вертеть память свою вспять,<br>
  Лететь, в самую пропасть стремясь,<br>
  Я уже не умею, не смею,<br>Не стану я.<br>
  <br>
  <strong>Припев:</strong>
  <br>Сердца из камня и стали,<br>
  Чужие сердца,<br>
  Мы историей стали,<br>
  Не придумав к ней конца,<br>
  Искать не надо друг друга<br>
  Нам даже во сне,<br>
  Позабудь, отпусти, <br>
  Лишь порою грусти обо мне, <br>
  Грусти обо мне<br>
  <br>
  Вдыхай новой весны зной,<br>
  Создай собственный мир свой,<br>
  Мой след потеряй в пыли,<br>
  Будем видеться как корабли<br>
  Только издали.<br><br>
  <strong>Припев:</strong>
  <br>Сердца из камня и стали,<br>
  Чужие сердца,<br>
  Мы историей стали,<br>
  Не придумав к ней конца,<br>
  Искать не надо друг друга<br>
  Нам даже во сне,<br>
  Позабудь, отпусти, <br>
  Лишь порою грусти обо мне, <br>
  Грусти обо мне.<br>
  <br>
  Пиши на адрес которого нет,<br>
  Спеши тени моей вслед,<br>
  В толпе профиль знакомый ищи,<br>
  За последнюю щепку цепляйся<br>
  Как тонущий.<br>
  <br>
  <strong>Припев:</strong>
  <br>Сердца из камня и стали,<br>
  Чужие сердца,<br>
  Мы историей стали,<br>
  Не придумав к ней конца,<br>
  Искать не надо друг друга<br>
  Нам даже во сне,<br>
  Позабудь, отпусти, <br>
  Лишь порою грусти обо мне, <br>
  Грусти обо мне.<br>                   
</p>
```

Как я сделал

1. Перешел по ссылке (браузер google)
2. Нажал F12
3. Нажал Select an element in the page to inspect it
4. Выбрал нужный элемент на странице и нажал ЛКМ (левая кнопка мыши )
5. Выделился тег
6. На этом теге нажал ПКМ (правая кнопка мыши)
7. Выбрал Copy => Copy element
8. Вставил в свой блокнот ...

Comment: вы неправильно поняли, я разработчик этого сайта, и обнаружил этот "косяк" с копированием, мне нужно чтобы когда посетители копировали текст он сохранил структуру колонки. Что у меня не так, как это исправить?

Comment: Но при копировании с "пиратских источников" текст колонкой, да и это не доп стиль, а стандартный html <p>,<br>

Comment: @Walker может обернуть в article  блок с песней ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, разобрался проблема была в другом - скрипте добавление ссылки в скопированный текст

Comment: @Walker я на другом сайте нашел тег prefix может он помочь ...

Comment: @Walker  можно подробнее ?  Вы скопировали текст откуда и там оказался скрипт ссылкой откуда Вы скопировали ?

Comment: В начале разработки был добавлен скрипт приписывающий ссылку на сайт после скопированного текста, и благополучно забыт. Нет у нас оригинальный текст предоставленный самой певицей

Comment: @Walker Извините если что ... меня интересует технический (если так можно назвать) аспект ...

Comment: Добавил скрипт в вопрос. Он перестирал строку сбивая структуру и добавлял в конце ссылку на сайт, при копировании содержимого сайта. К сожалению я плохо разбираюсь в JS и не могу точно сказать, что идет не так

Answer (score 1):

Используйте тег `<br>` для переноса строк, либо `\n` в UNIX.

К примеру:

```
<b><body>
    <p>
    ..... <br>
    ...... <br>
    ... ..... <br>
    </p>
</body></b>
```

Comment: Я и так использую `<br>` для переноса строки, однако при копировании перенос пропадает